# swift: about ternary operator Question. Why my code is error code??? Please tell me why I'm wrong

Tags: swift, operator-keyword, ternary

swift: about ternary operator Question. Why my code is error code??? Please tell me why I'm wrong.

```
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

var result = 0;

for a in 0..<arr.count{
    for b in 1..<arr.count - 1{
        for c in 2..<arr.count - 2 {
            arr[a] + arr[b] + arr[c] <= input[1] ? result = arr[a] + arr[b] +arr[c] : continue
        }
    }
}
```

[this is my error]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdiUB.png

Comment: It looks like this code should have quite a few errors — for instance, `{0,1,2...}` is not valid syntax for an array. However, when you share code like this, please include the actual error message text you're seeing so you can get specific help.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry I write wrong syntax.

Comment: You can't mix type/behaviour like that in a ternary operator (assignment : continue), rewrite the code without it. Normally you write it as `result = <Bool condition> ? <calculation/value> : <calculation/value>`

Comment: @sweetSwift Just a heads-up that general, it's preferred that you include the text of your error directly in the post rather than an image. (Both for accessibility, and since links break over time.)

Comment: thank you for telling me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift, the [ternary condition operator](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID387) is an *expression* which takes the form

```
<condition> ? <expression if true> : <expression if false>
```

[Expressions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#grammar_expression) are part of larger [statements](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html), and the ternary specifically is one which evaluates to either the *expression* after the `?`, or the one after the `:` depending on the truth of the condition.

`continue`, however, is not an *expression* but a [*statement* on its own](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#ID442), which means that it cannot be on either side of the ternary.

Thinking about this another way: expressions evaluate to some value (e.g., can be put on the right-hand-side of an assignment, like `x = <some expression>`), while statements do not (e.g., it doesn't make sense to write `x = continue`).

You will need to express this in the form of a regular `if`-statement then:

```swift
if arr[a] + arr[b] + arr[c] <= input[1] {
    result = arr[a] + arr[b] +arr[c]
} else {
    continue
}
```

Note that the above code might be *grammatically* correct (in that it will compile), but it is unlikely to be what you mean: the loop will automatically `continue` at the end of execution even if `arr[a] + arr[b] + arr[c] <= input[1]` *by default*, which means that your `result` may get overwritten later in the loop. It seems likely that you mean something like

```swift
outer_loop: for a in 0 ..< arr.count {
    for b in 1 ..< arr.count - 1 {
        for c in 2 ..< arr.count - 2 {
            if arr[a] + arr[b] + arr[c] <= input[1] {
                result = arr[a] + arr[b] + arr[c]

                // `break` would only exit the `c` loop, but with this label
                // we can exit all loops at once.
                break outer_loop
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand the condition of expression and ternary operator well. thank you. Additionally, thank you for letting us know about outer_loop.